# R: encoding issue with tm & wordcloud package

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

When trying to build a word cloud using the `wordcloud` package in `R`. I cannot get the generated cloud to display my special characters correctly. The example below highlights the problem:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)

data1 <- rbind("öööö", "ööö", "ööö", "ööö")

#Encoding(data1)  <- "UTF-8"

mach_corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(data1))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mach_corpus)
m <- as.matrix(tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
wordcloud(d$word,d$freq, scale=c(8,.2),min.freq=1,max.words=100, random.order=F, rot.per=.15, vfont=c("sans serif","plain"))
```

Looking at the steps in between, my character is showing up correctly in `m`, `v` and `d`. `Encoding()` tells me my words are in `latin1`, but trying to convert them into UTF-8 casts an error in `TermDocumentMatrix()`:

```
Error in .tolower(txt) : invalid input 'öööö' in 'utf8towcs'
```

On the other hand, saving my words in a text file that is encoded, and imported int `R`, as UTF-8 still ends in a messed up word cloud.

Comment: Removing the vfont=c("sans serif","plain") works in my case. The wordcloud then plots the correct characters.

Comment: You are correct, this solved my problem.